# ldapmodify: invalid format when trying to create olcObjectClass-

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to adda new object class to OpenLDAP and getting the following error, but can't see the issue:

```
# Add the securityPrincipal class
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.6 NAME 'securityPrincipal'
      DESC: 'Contains the security information for an object.'
      SUP top AUXILIARY 
      MUST ( $ sAMAccountName ) 
      MAY ( )
)
```

This is the error:

```
ldapmodify: invalid format (line 38) entry: "cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config"
```

which refers to this line:

```
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.6 NAME 'securityPrincipal'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue by putting everything on the same line and then the error was much clearer